# How can I capture frames from a Bodelin ProScope HR using AVCaptureSession on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: cocoa, video, osx-lion

I am attempting to grab frames and preview the video from a Bodelin Proscope HR USB microscope. I have a simple Cocoa app using an `AVCaptureSession` with an `AVCaptureDeviceInput` for the Proscope HR and a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` displaying the output.

All of this works fine with the built-in iSight camera, but the output from the Proscope HR is garbled beyond recognition.

Using the bundled Proscope software, I sometimes see the same garbling when trying to use the higher resolutions. My suspicion is that the hardware used is rather under-spec'd, and this is bolstered by the fact that at the lowest 320x200 resolution the bundled software grabs at 30fps, but when you bump up the resolutions the frame rates drop dramatically, down to 15fps at 640x480, all the way down to 3.75fps at the maximum resolution of 1600x1200.

EDIT: I originally thought that perhaps the frame rate being attempted by the AVCaptureSession was too high, but I have since confirmed that (at least in theory) the capture session is requesting the frame rate advertised by the AVCaptureDevice.

I should note that I have already tried all of the standard `AVCaptureSessionPreset*` constant presets defined in the headers, and none of them improved the results from the Proscope HR. (They did however appear to affect the built-in iSight in approximately the expected manner.)

Here is a screen capture showing the garbled output from the ProScope HR:

[image: ProScope HR output]

And just for comparison, the output from a generic WebCam:

[image: Generic WebCam output]

Comment: Could you attach short video that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/activeVideoMinFrameDuration) you should configure `AVCaptureDevice` rather than `AVCaptureSession`.

**EDIT:**
The AV framework is developed on top of IOKit and it fully relies on the fact that you have no problems with hardware. In your case, it looks like the root of your problem is hardware-related so you should consider using IOKit directly.

Comment: I have confirmed using the debugger that the AVCaptureDevice capabilities are used automatically by AVCaptureSession… So I was off target suspecting the frame rate was bad. There is some other issue seemingly unique to the ProScope HR.

Comment: So you tried to assign different values to AVCaptureDevice's activeVideoMinFrameDuration property?

Comment: I did, and it still did not produce any usable output from the ProScope HR device. I suspect that there is something non-conformant about Bodelin's hardware, despite the fact that they advertise it as requiring no special drivers for MacOS X.

Comment: Then you should consider to use IOKit directly rather than using the AV framework.